# How can we reverse the keys and values of hash with an efficient algorithm like this?

Tags: algorithm, hash

- Think like you are implementing Like function of chat app.
- You wanna store the information all people's name who liked a specific comment in db.
- for memory reason, you don't wanna store the information which comments a specific person liked so far in db.

So what you wanna do is

```
# commend-id1: (user1, user2, user3)
# comment-id2: (user2]
# comment-id3: (user1)

# You wanna convert above into below by some codes

# user1: (comment-id1, comment-id3)
# user2: (comment-id2)
# user3: (comment-id1)
```

Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

---

EDIT::

someone commented the above example is impossible with efficient way.

how about this?

```
data = {
    "field_a": {
        "name": "index_a",
        "used_fields": ["a", "b", "c"]
    },
    "field_b": {
        "name": "index_b",
        "used_fields": ["d", "b", "d"]
    },
    "field_c": {
        "name": "index_c",
        "used_fields": ["a"]
    }
}

# you wanna convert above into below

# a. index_a, index_c
# b. index_a, index_b
# c. index_a
```

Comment: normally, no. you have to iterate over all the keys and values of the first map to create the second one. there is normally no relation between the key and the value that you could potentially use to decrease the amount of work you need. unless they are stored in some special structure that has some pre-computated data.

Comment: hmm. how about second example? I edited the question now. @user1984